# How to add mac os support to a flutter package project?

Tags: flutter, macos

I have tried running the terminal command:

```
flutter config --enable-macos-desktop
```

but it gives me error:

```
The "--platforms" argument is not supported in package template
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for an existing project just run

`flutter create --platforms=macos .`

See also here some official docs from the flutter website:
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/desktop#add-desktop-support-to-an-existing-flutter-app

Comment: Works even on old Flutter versions (2.8.0). Thanks!

Comment: It generates the macos folder but it also corrupted my git repository.

Answer (score 1):

I have found work around:

1. copy mac os folder from a new natural flutter project(non-package):
2. open terminal & run:

   cd example/macos

3.run:

```
pod install
```

then

```
flutter run
```